# Prisoner Probability

Tags: probability

In the United States the probability that a prisoner paroled from federal prison will return to prison within $2$ years is $\frac13$. Among $10$ prisoners what are:

a. $P(3 \text{ return})$

$$P(X=3)=\binom{10}{3}(1/3)^3(2/3)^{10-3}$$
$$=\frac{10!}{3!7!}(1/27)(2/3)^7$$
$$=0.2601$$

b. $P(\text{at least }4\text{ return})$

$$P(at least 4)=1-P(X<4)$$
$$=1-(\binom{10}{0}[(1/3)^0(2/3)^{10}+\binom{10}{1}(1/3)^1(2/3)^{9}+\binom{10}{2}(1/3)^2(2/3)^{8}+\binom{10}{3}(1/3)^3(2/3)^{7})$$
$$=1-\frac{33024}{59049}$$
$$=0.4407$$

c. $P(\text{the number who return is at least } 2\text{ but not more than }4)$

$$P(2≤X≤4)=P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)=\binom{10}{2}(1/3)^2+(2/3)^8+\binom{10}{3}(1/3)^3+(2/3)^7+\binom{10}{4}(1/3)^4+(2/3)^6$$
$$=0.6828$$

(especially unsure about c)

Comment: It is the right thinking for this type of problem.

Comment: Is it not? It was in that section of the textbook so I guess I just assumed, then another distribution, such as geometric? To be honest, it's not very clear to me when to use one distribution over another

Comment: How many paroled prisoners are there? Quite a lot I think. Each of $10$ prisoners in the sample can be looked at as an experiment that can succeed or fail, and is independent of the other experiments. I am telling you that it *is* the right thinking. If you have still doubts, then why?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I read it as is it, not it is.  So for b. I would do the same except with starting with (10 4) etc etc and c. would be (10 4) etc minus (10 2) etc

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: You are correct with a) and b). For c) note that the "allowed" numbers of returning parolees are $2$, $3$, and $4$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter how does my answer for c look now?

Comment: @Math Major: It's of course $(1/3)^2(2/3)^8$ instead of $(1/3)^2+(2/3)^8$, and similarly for the other two. I thought it was just a typo; but the correct value is $0.4552$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (c):

\begin{align*}
P(2 \leq X \leq 4) &= P(X=2) + P(X=3) + P(X=4) \\
&= \binom{10}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8+\binom{10}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7+\binom{10}{4}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks! I realize now I was just overthinking it